# Go up the bed vs go to bed

Tags: grammar, prepositions

It's bedtime.

I make a bottle for him.

"Go to bed and drink" I passed the bottle to him.

```
Go up the bed.

Go to bed.
```

Do I need to add up when I asking him to climb up the bed?

Comment: No.  The standard idiom is "Go to bed."

Comment: No. "Go to bed" should be fine.

Comment: You can say either "go to bed" or "get into bed".

Comment: Is this a baby or a small child? How tall the child is, and ability to walk, affect how you would answer this. "go to bed* almost always is fine. "Go up *to* bed" implies the bed is relatively higher, or in an upstairs room if the child can climb the stairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the figure of speech that you should know about to answer such questions is Prepositions.

> [Prepositions](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/prepositions) are used to express some logical relation between any two objects in a given sentence.

For example,

> The cat jumped over the wall,
>
> The fruit fell into the well,
>
> The boy swam across the river, etc.

In all the above sentences, the italicized words "over", "into" and "across" are the known as prepositions. These words connect the nouns in any given statement and make the sentence more logical and clear to comprehend.

The use of prepositions is completely situation dependent. For instance, if the in my first example statement, the cat is jumping from one wall to another, the statement would have been like `The cat jumped across the wall.`

So, now coming to your statement, `Go to bed` fits more than `Go up the bed` because of the difference in their usages.

As a preposition "**up**" is used to talk about position in or movement to a higher or more important place or degree etc. On other hand, "**to**" is used when one needs to indicate that there is movement from one place to another. Hence, the preposition '**to**' should be used with verbs such as drive, walk, go, hike, fly, sail, etc.

The above explanation should suffice for why I said that "***Go to bed***" is correct sentence construction.